# Qt5 static linking fails on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, build, static-linking

Here is what I did:
1. Downloaded sources
2. `./configure -static -prefix /home/user/build/qt-static/build -qt-xcb`
3. `make -j3`
4. `make install`
5. After 1h of building, I made a simple test.cpp:

```
    #include <QtGui>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;
    window.resize(250, 150);
    window.setWindowTitle("Test");
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
    }
```

6. Created a project file: `/home/user/build/final/bin/qmake -project`

   ```
   TEMPLATE = app
   TARGET = test
   INCLUDEPATH += .  # missing path ?
   # I also tried adding CONFIG += widgets or CONFIG += static, both resulting in the same errors
   SOURCES += test.cpp
   ```
7. Created a Makefile: `/home/user/build/final/bin/qmake *pro`
   Part of the Makefile:

   ```
   #############################################################################
   # Makefile for building: stat
   # Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.7.1)
   # Project:  stat.pro
   # Template: app
   # Command: /home/user/build/final/bin/qmake -config release -o Makefile stat.pro
   #############################################################################

   MAKEFILE      = Makefile

   ####### Compiler, tools and options

   CC            = gcc
   CXX           = g++
   DEFINES       = -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
   CFLAGS        = -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
   CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
   INCPATH       = -I. -I. -I../build/final/include -I../build/final/include/QtGui -I../build/final/include/QtCore -I. -I../build/final/mkspecs/linux-g++
   QMAKE         = /home/user/build/final/bin/qmake
   DEL_FILE      = rm -f
   CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
   MKDIR         = mkdir -p
   COPY          = cp -f
   COPY_FILE     = cp -f
   COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
   INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
   INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
   INSTALL_DIR   = cp -f -R
   DEL_FILE      = rm -f
   SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
   DEL_DIR       = rmdir
   MOVE          = mv -f
   TAR           = tar -cf
   COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
   DISTNAME      = stat1.0.0
   DISTDIR = /home/user/stat/.tmp/stat1.0.0
   LINK          = g++
   LFLAGS        = -Wl,-O1
   LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -L/home/user/build/final/lib -L/home/user/build/final/plugins/platforms -lqxcb -L/home/user/build/final/plugins/xcbglintegrations -lqxcb-egl-integration -lqxcb-glx-integration -lxcb-glx -lQt5XcbQpa -lSM -lICE -lxcb-static -L/home/user/build/final/plugins/imageformats -lqdds -lqicns -lqico -lqtga -lqtiff -lqwbmp -lqwebp -L/home/user/build/final/plugins/egldeviceintegrations -lqeglfs-x11-integration -lX11-xcb -lxcb -lQt5EglDeviceIntegration -lQt5PlatformSupport -lQt5DBus -lqtfreetype -lXext -lX11 -lQt5Gui -lqtpng -lqtharfbuzzng -lQt5Core -lz -lqtpcre -lm -ldl -lrt -lEGL -lGL -lpthread 
   AR            = ar cqs
   RANLIB        = 
   SED           = sed
   STRIP         = strip

   ####### Output directory

   OBJECTS_DIR   = ./

   ####### Files

   SOURCES       = test.cpp /home/user/stat/stat_plugin_import.cpp
   OBJECTS       = test.o \
           stat_plugin_import.o
   DIST          = ../build/final/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/linux.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/sanitize.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dcore.pri \
           #CUT
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf \
           .qmake.stash \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/qt.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/moc.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/unix/opengl.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/file_copies.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/exceptions.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
           stat.pro  test.cpp
   QMAKE_TARGET  = stat
   DESTDIR       = 
   TARGET        = stat


   first: all
   ####### Build rules

   $(TARGET): /home/user/build/final/lib/libQt5Gui.a /home/user/build/final/lib/libQt5Core.a $(OBJECTS)  
       $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJCOMP) $(LIBS)

   Makefile: stat.pro ../build/final/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf ../build/final/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/linux.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/sanitize.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dcore.pri \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dcore_private.pri \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dextras.pri \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dextras_private.pri \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dinput.pri \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dinput_private.pri \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dlogic.pri \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dlogic_private.pri \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dquick.pri \
           #CUT
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
           ../build/final/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
           stat.pro \
           ../build/final/lib/libQt5Gui.prl \
           ../build/final/lib/libQt5Core.prl \
           ../build/final/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.prl \
           ../build/final/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.prl \
           ../build/final/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.prl \
           ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqdds.prl \
           ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.prl \
           ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqico.prl \
           ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.prl \
           ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.prl \
           ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.prl \
           ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.prl \
           ../build/final/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-x11-integration.prl
       $(QMAKE) -config release -o Makefile stat.pro
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/common/unix.conf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/common/linux.conf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/common/sanitize.conf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/qconfig.pri:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dcore.pri:
   #CUT
   ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtuiotouchplugin.pri:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtvirtualkeyboardplugin.pri:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qwbmp.pri:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qwebp.pri:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qxcb-egl-integration.pri:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qxcb-glx-integration.pri:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qxcb.pri:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf:
   .qmake.stash:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/qt.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/resources.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/moc.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/unix/opengl.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/file_copies.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/exceptions.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf:
   ../build/final/mkspecs/features/lex.prf:
   stat.pro:
   ../build/final/lib/libQt5Gui.prl:
   ../build/final/lib/libQt5Core.prl:
   ../build/final/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.prl:
   ../build/final/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.prl:
   ../build/final/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.prl:
   ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqdds.prl:
   ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.prl:
   ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqico.prl:
   ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.prl:
   ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.prl:
   ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.prl:
   ../build/final/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.prl:
   ../build/final/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-x11-integration.prl:
   qmake: FORCE
       @$(QMAKE) -config release -o Makefile stat.pro

   qmake_all: FORCE


   all: Makefile $(TARGET)

   dist: distdir FORCE
       (cd `dirname $(DISTDIR)` && $(TAR) $(DISTNAME).tar $(DISTNAME) && $(COMPRESS) $(DISTNAME).tar) && $(MOVE) `dirname $(DISTDIR)`/$(DISTNAME).tar.gz . && $(DEL_FILE) -r $(DISTDIR)

   distdir: FORCE
       @test -d $(DISTDIR) || mkdir -p $(DISTDIR)
       $(COPY_FILE) --parents $(DIST) $(DISTDIR)/
       $(COPY_FILE) --parents test.cpp $(DISTDIR)/


   clean: compiler_clean 
       -$(DEL_FILE) $(OBJECTS)
       -$(DEL_FILE) *~ core *.core


   distclean: clean 
       -$(DEL_FILE) $(TARGET) 
       -$(DEL_FILE) /home/user/stat/stat_plugin_import.cpp .qmake.stash
       -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile


   ####### Sub-libraries

   mocclean: compiler_moc_header_clean compiler_moc_source_clean

   mocables: compiler_moc_header_make_all compiler_moc_source_make_all

   check: first

   benchmark: first

   compiler_rcc_make_all:
   compiler_rcc_clean:
   compiler_moc_header_make_all:
   compiler_moc_header_clean:
   compiler_moc_source_make_all:
   compiler_moc_source_clean:
   compiler_yacc_decl_make_all:
   compiler_yacc_decl_clean:
   compiler_yacc_impl_make_all:
   compiler_yacc_impl_clean:
   compiler_lex_make_all:
   compiler_lex_clean:
   compiler_clean: 

   ####### Compile

   test.o: test.cpp ../build/final/include/QtGui/QtGui \
           ../build/final/include/QtGui/QtGuiDepends \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/QtCore \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/QtCoreDepends \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/qabstractanimation.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/qobject.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/qglobal.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/qconfig.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/qfeatures.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/qsystemdetection.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/qprocessordetection.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/qcompilerdetection.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/qtypeinfo.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtCore/qtypetraits.h \
           #CUT
           ../build/final/include/QtGui/qtextobject.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtGui/qtextdocumentfragment.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtGui/qtextdocumentwriter.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtGui/qtextlist.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtGui/qtexttable.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtGui/qdesktopservices.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtGui/qvalidator.h \
           ../build/final/include/QtGui/qtguiversion.h
       $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o test.o test.cpp

   stat_plugin_import.o: /home/user/stat/stat_plugin_import.cpp 
       $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o stat_plugin_import.o /home/user/stat/stat_plugin_import.cpp

   ####### Install

   install:  FORCE

   uninstall:  FORCE

   FORCE:
   ```
8. `make` results in errors:

   ```
   Makefile:1169: warning: overriding commands for target `stat_plugin_import.o'
   Makefile:808: warning: ignoring old commands for target `stat_plugin_import.o'
   g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I../build/final/include -I../build/final/include/QtGui -I../build/final/include/QtCore -I. -I../build/final/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o test.o test.cpp
   test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
   test.cpp:3:22: error: variable ‘QApplication app’ has initializer but incomplete type
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
                         ^
   test.cpp:4:5: error: ‘QMainWindow’ was not declared in this scope
        QMainWindow window;
        ^
   test.cpp:4:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘window’
        QMainWindow window;
                    ^
   test.cpp:5:5: error: ‘window’ was not declared in this scope
        window.resize(250, 150);
        ^
   make: *** [test.o] Error 1
   ```
9. So I read the official documentation, and tried the following commands:
   `PATH=/home/user/build/final/bin:$PATH`
   `export PATH`
   `qmake -config release`
   `make`
   But I'm getting the same errors like above
10. Changing `#include <QtGui>` to `#include <QApplication>` and `#include <QMainWindow>` returns:

    ```
    g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I../build/final/include -I../build/final/include/QtGui -I../build/final/include/QtCore -I. -I../build/final/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o test.o test.cpp
    test.cpp:2:24: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
     #include <QApplication>
                            ^
    compilation terminated.
    make: *** [test.o] Error 1
    ```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: `CONFIG += widgets` to .pro file.

Comment: @AlexanderVX: This does not work.  I get the same errors like before

Comment: `QT += widgets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
#include <QtGui>
```

to

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
```

AlexanderXV's comment is good because it tells the linker to use QtWidgets and sets the correct path for the compiler. In Qt5, the command in .pro file is:

```
QT += widgets
```

source : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-index.html

PLUS:

you can use the single `#include <QtWidgets>`, it includes all other header files from QtWidgets.

Comment: I added 10. to the main post

Comment: try `QT += widgets` instead of `CONFIG += widgets`, you makefile does not use qtwidgets - source: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-index.html

Comment: Perfect! Add this to your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Don't use `include <QtWidgets>` in production code. That pulls in every include related to that module which would just slow down your build time. Include only what you use.